# Changing one item from float to fixed positioning, CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I am currently designing a basic website and I am wanting to change how my navigation bar on the left hand side acts, I want it to remain where it is but I want it to have fixed positioning so that you can scroll with it remaining there.

My question is, is there anyway of changing it's position to fixed without it moving around and messing up my work in getting everything else positioned correctly, I will link to a image of the website and included the HTML and CSS.

As an extra question, can anyone tell me why the website looks different when I run the HTML through different browsers, I am currently using Google chrome. I thought using px values got rid of this problem.

**EDIT 2**
Here are the screenshots for different browsers on two different screens.
The webpage was designed for google chrome on my laptop which has a resolution of 1600x900.
The computer I am comparing with has a resolution of 1440x900.
Any adjustments to the window cause problems, never aginwill I zoom.
This link goes to a gallery with 8 images. http://postimg.org/gallery/908tlytw/

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso10646"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-GB"/>
    <meta name="author" content="###########"/>
    <meta name="designer" content="##########"/>
    <meta name="description" content="The official website of ##########, promoting her humanist services."/>
    <!--<meta name="keywords" content="##########, humanist"/>-->
    <meta name="language" content="english"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
    <meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet lego.css"/>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">

        <div class="toparea">
            <img src="Client's Logo.png" id="logo"/>
            <h1 id="title">Significant Ceremonies by ##########</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Tel: ############</li>
                <li>E-mail: #######################</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="sidearea">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Humanism</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Planning</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Specialist Areas</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="mainarea">
            <h2 id="subtitle">Home</h2>
            <p>"I would rather live a life based on honesty, compassion and humanity through my own free will instead of it coming from the fear of
                divine beings." - ###########</p>
            <p>Welcome to my web site, here you can find information about the services I perform and about Humanism itself. Please feel free to 
                navigate around my site and if you have any questions you can either contact me directly or use the form on the 'Contact Me' page.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="bottomarea">
            <ul>
                <li>Tel: ############</li>
                <li>E-mail: #######################</li>
            </ul>
            <img src="BHA logo.jpg" id="bhalogo"/>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
body
{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#page
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #E6F5E6;
    font-family: vijaya, sakkal majalla, narkisim, monotype corsiva, jasmineupc, gabriola, french script mt, footlight mt light, calisto mt, papyrus;
}

.toparea
{
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#logo
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#title
{
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 160px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #002E00;
}

.toparea ul
{
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 40px;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidearea
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.sidearea ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.sidearea ul li
{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: #4DB84D;
    border-color: #002E00;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.sidearea ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#subtitle
{
    color: #002E00;
}

.mainarea
{
    float: left;
    width: 560px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    /*background-color: #EEF8EE;*/
}

.bottomarea
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.bottomarea ul
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 360px;
    width: 610px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#bhalogo
{
    position: fixed;
    right: 388px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: It looks different on different browsers, because they use different engines to render the page, and also different default style sheets.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  If you want the bar on the side to stay in the same place when you scroll.  then you need to set its position to fixed.  If you designed your website well.. you should need to adjust this in one place and the rest of your site will be consistent with the change

Comment: to fix your multiple browser issue you can try a css reset

something like this :  http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand the link? Is it coded to be added that seeks to nullify any changes when using a different browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to 'float' the menu on the left without making too many changes to your html. You can do this by adding another div that has the the same style as your `.sidearea` (width, height, etc) but otherwise has no content, as a placeholder, and change the style for `.sidearea` to say `position:fixed`.

The different browser issue is more subtle: it depends on custom font availability, default CSS the browser uses, etc. It is usually fixed by looking at the differences issue by issue.

Comment: Thanks for the work around, I never thought of using a placeholder so the main content area stays in the same place. I'm presuming I'll just have to open the webpage in multiple browsers and play around until it looks the same on each.

Comment: My apologies, it seems to be that it only looks different when on a different computer, although when I put it on that computer it then looked different on each browser I tried whereas on my computer it remains the same.

Comment: Browser compatibility is tricky and trying them one by one is the only reliable way to go. If the differences are due to different fonts, the only way to go is to use more generic options (or stick to CSS3 compatible browsers only and import your own fonts, or (worst option) use graphics). If the answers work for you do not forget to vote.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't determine whether it is browser compatibility or resolution problems as on my laptop all browsers are the same but on the home computer each browser is different and they all look wrong. Also I wish I could vote up but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Can you post a couple of different screenshots with wrong looking results? How does resizing the browser window affect everything?

Comment: I'll collect screenshots of the site being run through different browsers on different screens, I'll add them in around 3-4 hours.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshots of the webpage displayed through four of the main browsers on two different computers, see 'EDIT 2' for the link and some extra information. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this   `position:fixed;top:10%;left:4%;`...example :: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yt67A/)**

value of top: and left is just an example,change it to fit your need

Comment: The problem was that because the main content area floats 'against' the navigation area when its position is changed to fixed the main content area shifts around the page.